# Sessions in my web app are mixing

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have web app, and this is scenario

User is logging in.
Data is loaded from db added to Object (e.g)

```
class UserData
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and instance of this object is added into session, when user from another computer log in then his session is also applied to first user session. I know this because there is name displayed in header of app.

Server IIS7, ASP.NET 2.0 C#

I still can't believe how this can be possible, but can't find solution that is reason I'm asking.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you multiple browser windows open at the same time?

Comment: You'll really need to provide more information for anyone to help you out with this. There are lots of ways this could get mixed up if you're coding it the wrong way.

Comment: Yes, more code with be appropriate.

Comment: I have tried on multiple browsers and also multiple computers, I know how session is working but this is strange..

Comment: Well how are you storing this information in the session?  We need code.

Comment: Session["User.Data"] = myUserDataObject;
when retrieving (UserData)Session["User.Data"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will probably be the need for more information.
Check if you do not store this user data in a static object. This object might be shared across sessions.

Do you see the first or the second/last person's name (in the order of logging in) on your screen?
This might also be a case of output caching. Do you know how to trace or debug your webapplication? Can you verify the correct data is stored in the session?

Comment: Thanks man, I had one static variable in order not to cast it through same request, that was problem, thanks, I love you, I thought that I'm loosing my mind.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Sometimes thinking your loosing your mind must be part of a developers life. It sounds familiar. But eh, don't declare your love to everyone! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY way this can happen is if you are either caching data on the server side, caching at a proxy level (improperly), or your logic to display that information isn't properly determining the user. Is it just reading it from the database?
Turn tracing on the page at the top add Trace="true"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx

and ensure the aspnet session id is really unique between both sessions. They wont combine together so something else is going on here.